# What would be the cheapest way to host host large amount of data online?

Tags: hosting, storage

I would like to keep large amount of data in an Internet accessible place. Starting at, say, 80TB and increasing the storage gradually. 80TB, ->160TB after maybe a year, ->240 after one more year or so. Something like that.

The requirements are mostly store only, regular files. Almost no download, not too much upload, say, constant ~100Mbit upload 24/7 for start.

What would be the cheapest way to rent/buy such storage arrays. Backups are welcome, but are very optional, 100% availability is welcome, but optional. The aim is to get cheap storage and to have it somewhere where I can access it. Anything, even AWS like services are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just for you? Then I would suggest to setup a fileserver of your own as 80TB of online storage can get **really** pricy, seeing that 2TB of online storage costs ~$8/month. But if you set up a server with one (or more) SANs you'd be cheaper off on the long run. And its under *your* control.

Anyway if its for others too, you can configure it to be an FTP server as well, if needed.

Comment: Pretty much yes, I can manage with only one PC accessing the storage. But I have no idea what type of hardware and at what cost I can throw at the problem.

Comment: Where have you found a storage at ~8$/mo for 2TB? That's actually very cheap compared to what I've found.

Comment: [$10/month for 2 TB online storage](http://www.livedrive.com/ForHome/Briefcase).
And here an how-to on making your own [67 TB fileserver for (only) $7,867](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/)

Comment: $10/mo for 2TB doesn't sound realistic given that raw hardware costs ~$250/2TB, no hosting, no redundancy. There must be a catch, at least if I'll start storing 250TB+.

Comment: I think the [how-to](http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/) I linked would be the cheapest. Either way, it's gonna be pricey if you want **that** much storage